# Doctrine - Get sells between two dates

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Got this entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="shop_payment_details")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\ShopBundle\Entity\PaymentRepository")
 */
class Payment extends ArrayObject
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     *
     * @var integer $id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\ShopBundle\Entity\Item")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="item_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    protected $item;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $date;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="amount", type="float", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $amount;
```

I need to file a sales table between two dates he selected.
The table must contain all days between two dates and reference codes of the objects in the store.

For example:
[image: Example of table im searching to do]

How can I get it? Can do it just with Doctrine or i must use PHP to build that table?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, what you need is the `orX()` function supplied by Doctrine-ORM


You will need to create two expressions using the function `exp()` then you can put both expressions in the `orX()` statement to get the wanted results.

For the expressions you need to define you will need the function
 `gt()/lt()` - *greater than/ lower than*
This will give you the possibility to compare two dates

For a further reference check this link:
https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#high-level-api-methods

**PS:** 
For readabilty and logic it should be easier to create the expression before inserting them into your query:

```
$exp1 = $qb->expr()->gt('..', '?value');
$exp2 = $qb->expr()->gt('..', '?value2'),

...

$qb->where($qb->expr()->orX($exp1, $exp2));
```

Notice that `orX` can aggregate an unlimited number of expressions

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom DQL (in a repository I suggest) to retrieve all payments where payment.date => yourSmallerUserDate and payment.date <= yourBiggerUserDate.

The result will be all payments between your two dates.

Within your logic you build a table with a row per day between your two dates. And whenever you have a date in your result matching your row date add it to your output.